# Deferred page loading in Fluter Web with Router

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

I am working on optimizing the initial page load of my Flutter web app. One path I am investigating is to reduce the binary size of `main.dart.js` by splitting it into parts using [deferred loading](https://dart.dev/language/libraries#lazily-loading-a-library).

I am using [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) which as far as I know doesn't support lazy loading. I have heard about [`auto_route`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) which supposedly supports such feature but it's *undocumented*.